# Java source code dependency graph

Tags: java, programming-languages, module, dependencies

Well, first of all, this could potentially be stupid and crazy.

I am trying to build (or use, if there already exists one) a framework, which takes in a number of Java source files and outputs the way these files interact; for example, file1.java could *import* file2.java; file2.java could call a *static* method from file3.java. It would ideally be great, if this could be done without compiling or running the set of files. I am aware of the Reflection API that allows me to explore the parts of a class, but is that what I am looking for?

Also, how hard is this to extend to other languages, for example, Python, or Lisp (add any other language here)?

I was not really sure how to construct the question title, so if something like this has been asked before, I'd be glad if you could link me to that question.

Comment: Technically, you don't import files - the import is simply used by the compiler to resolve fully qualified class names when non-fully qualified class names are used.

Comment: Via reflection, you can look at the fields in a class, the arguments and return types of the methods -- but reflection won't tell you anything about classes that are used *within* a method.

Comment: Check out the source of OpenJDK? I think you are doing something that the compiler is doing already.

Comment: There should be a variety of UML tools which can do close to this.  They would show which Objects are related, not files, but Java has a pretty close coupling between the two so the UML dependency chart will get you close.

Comment: @GregKopff Yes, I had the same limitation of reflection in mind.

Comment: @nhahtdh sure, that's pretty valid, but how feasible?

Comment: @Thomas Right, I'll have a look at those. But for other languages?

Answer (score 2):

i am currently working on a project , the main function is very similar to what you mentioned , and i use the javaparser : http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/

javaparser is very powerful , it can help us a lot in source code analysis , but it is very hard to get the full dependencies and classes interactions even if i use javaparser.

For example:
if you want to get all the dependencies of a class , the most directly approach is to get the "import" area of the source code - this is very easy by using javaparser.

But only the "import" is not enough , if the class - ClassA - you are currently analyzing called a class - ClassB - which is in the same package with ClassA , then ClassB will not appears in the import area .

So in this situation , we can not get the ClassB dependency.

And for the interactive of classes , if you can not 100% get the right dependencies of a class , then you can not 100% know the right interactive between classes.

But anyway , up to now, the javaparser is the most powerful and useful java source code analyze tool i can find .

Comment: OK, i would suggest to use : ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org/) this time. ANTLR is the best solution for programming language parse and process.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked two questions and I will try to address the first one. I believe you are doing some kind of source analysis of java files to see how they could interact with each other (at least that's what I understood) So basically to do this you have to act a bit like the Eclipse IDE. Scanning the source code in each .java file and constructing data structures of java reserved words and constructs. Once each .java file has been analyzed you can then proceed to discover the links between them.

ex.

1. Store the package name of the class and its name and its scope
2. Store a HashMap of all declared variables, their values and their scope
3. Discover the methods in the source file and store their names, in + out parameters and scope

You can do a lot more too and to detect these constructs you'd have to write your own (or find something on the net) parser and use regular expressions to detect these. You store them in your program and then once all source files are analyzed, you can begin to see the interactions.

ex.

Source file 1 is in package x.y and has 3 public methods and 2 package scope methods.
Source file 2 is in package z and has 1 public method and 3 private methods.

So you can conclude that file 1 can interact with file 2 by invoking that 1 public method. And you can do the same analysis for all the files.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I'm not sure how feasible it is. I'll probably wait for more answers.

Comment: It is 100% feasible, we learn this stuff in university. Usually course goes by the name of "compiler construction." You're basically looking at coding a parser and analyzing the source code and mapping every single portion of it. Then you just find the connection between the mappings based on rules. and those rules are defined in the JVM specs.

Comment: If there is time I could write you a sample program that does what I mentioned. Like something really basic as a proof of concept if you doubt the feasibility of what I am suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you'd rather not do the compile, but it would be far easier to look through the class files. Between the bytecode and the constants pool you can get everything you need without resorting to essentially rewriting javac. Use Apache BCEL and you're mostly there. Obviously no tool will be able to find dependencies accessed through reflection; for that you'd need to do runtime analysis with a custom classloader or something.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/

Comment: It might be easier, but it would also be wrong. javac inlines constants across source files, meaning that you can have A.java depending on B.java, but A.class with no references to B.class.

Answer (score 0):

For someone coming across this question in 2023 or later, seems like this work was done by Patrick Beuks and Darius Sas as their [Bachelor thesis](https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/20150/1/bCS_2019_BeuksPA.pdf) , and the code [open sourced](https://github.com/darius-sas/pyne). While it is usually preferable to have standalone answers in Stackoverflow, there's no way to do that here without copy-pasting the thesis or the code, which makes no sense and would be unethical.

Edit:

I attempted to use the software, but it requires building from source, and makes childish assumptions that fail the build. Thus, like many academic projects, this one too fails to work without a lot of time and effort invested by the user.

You wanted to scan source code, but there's a popular open source software that can scan class files.
https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph